# Laravel auto translate $request

Tags: php, laravel, google-translate

I have two table in my database. The first is industry and the second is industry_languages.

Industry's table

```
Schema::create('industries', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('industry_name', 100);
        $table->integer('language_id')->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Industry_Languages' table

```
Schema::create('industry_languages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('industry_id');
        $table->string('industry_name', 200);
        $table->integer('language_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This is my IndustryController

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $industry = new Industry();
    $industry->industry_name = $request->industryName;
    $industry->save();

    return response()->json($industry);
}
```

This function will only store data into industry's table with language id = 1, but I also want to store it into industry_languages' table with language id = 2 (because I have a language's table in my database with 2 row data: 'Indonesia', 'English')

Example: If I input 'Halo' in the industry_name field, It will store into my industry's table as 'Halo' in the industry_name field and '1' in the language_id field, then It will also store into my industry_languages' table as 'Hello' in the industry_name field and '2' in the language_id field

I have a problem with translating the request from the industry's table.
I have tried to use `Laravel google-translate` but, it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to use [this pakcage](https://github.com/ddctd143/google-translate)

But, it needs Google Translate API key and I think that's not free. So, I have found a package that's not need to generate API KEY: [statickidz/php-google-translate-free](https://github.com/statickidz/php-google-translate-free)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using https://github.com/spatie/laravel-translatable ?

Using `laravel-translatable` you could do something like

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $industry = new Industry(); 
    $industry
    ->setTranslation('industryName', 'en', 'Hello')
    ->setTranslation('industryName', 'es', $request->get('industryName'));

    $industry->save();

    return response()->json($industry);
}
```

For the other languages you might need to use a translator package

Comment: this is manual, I want to store it automatically, like If I store 'halo', It will automatically translate as 'hello'

Comment: @JamesRiady You could replace the 'Hello' with a translation function. For example with [google-translate](https://github.com/ddctd143/google-translate) you could do: 


`$translator = new Dedicated\GoogleTranslate\Translator;
$result = $translator->setSourceLang('es')
                     ->setTargetLang('en')
                     ->translate($request->get('industryName'));
      
$industry->setTranslation('industryName', 'en', $result)`

Comment: I have tried that packages, but It occurs error in `$translator` , it does not find the class

Comment: Have you tried `$translator = new \Dedicated\GoogleTranslate\Translator;`?

Comment: yes, but it occurs an error that it could not find the class

Comment: For issues regarding the package i suggest you open a issue on their [github](https://github.com/ddctd143/google-translate/issues) or you could try to use a other package

Comment: I have seen the all the issues of the package, but I saw that all their issues didn't read by the package maker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159137/discussion-between-amando-vledder-and-james-riady).

Comment: you follow the example of google-translate and it works fine for you, isn't it?

Comment: its working fine for me but let us [continue this in chat.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159137/discussion-between-amando-vledder-and-james-riady)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. I think the problem is the API KEY.. the google translate key is not free

Comment: Lets not get off-topic in the comments about translate packages. For further discussions about translate packages we can [continue this in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159137/discussion-between-amando-vledder-and-james-riady)